# AngularJS - Restheart API (MongoDB) - Parsing the JSON result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, rest

I am using ***RestHeart*** to expose CRUD operations from ***MongoBD***. And trying to invoke the Rest API from ***AngularJS*** and get the JSON result as in below JSON string. But I am interested only in the **name, age & city** fields which I stored in the MongoDB.

I am not sure how to get these values.

**Javascript code:-**

```
crudApp.controller('listController', function($scope, $http, $location,
    crudService) {

$http.get('http://localhost:8081/jaydb/employees').success(
        function(response) {
            console.log('response : ' +JSON.stringify(response));
            $scope.employees = response;
        });
```

})

**JSON Result from REST API**

```
{
_embedded: {
rh: doc: [
  {
    _embedded: {

    },
    _links: {
      self: {
        href: "/jaydb/employees/55c1e7c41c49a8cd78818bc7"
      },
      rh: coll: {
        href: "/jaydb"
      },
      curies: [
        {
          href: "http://www.restheart.org/docs/v0.10/#api-doc-{rel}",
          name: "rh"
        }
      ]
    },
    _type: "DOCUMENT",
    _id: {
      $oid: "55c1e7c41c49a8cd78818bc7"
    },
```

> ```
>     name: "Anupama",
>     city: "Trichy",
>     age: 25,
> ```

```
    _etag: {
      $oid: "55c1e7c41c49a8cd78818bc8"
    },
    _lastupdated_on: "2015-08-05T10:39:00Z",
    _created_on: "2015-08-05T10:39:00Z"
  },
  {
    _embedded: {

    },
    _links: {
      self: {
        href: "/jaydb/employees/55c1e7ae1c49a8cd78818bc5"
      },
      rh: coll: {
        href: "/jaydb"
      },
      curies: [
        {
          href: "http://www.restheart.org/docs/v0.10/#api-doc-{rel}",
          name: "rh"
        }
      ]
    },
    _type: "DOCUMENT",
    _id: {
      $oid: "55c1e7ae1c49a8cd78818bc5"
    },
name: "Sujatha",
city: "Chennai",
age: 24,
    _etag: {
      $oid: "55c1e7ae1c49a8cd78818bc6"
    },
    _lastupdated_on: "2015-08-05T10:38:38Z",
    _created_on: "2015-08-05T10:38:38Z"
  },
  {
    _embedded: {

    },
    _links: {
      self: {
        href: "/jaydb/employees/55c1e7981c49a8cd78818bc3"
      },
      rh: coll: {
        href: "/jaydb"
      },
      curies: [
        {
          href: "http://www.restheart.org/docs/v0.10/#api-doc-{rel}",
          name: "rh"
        }
      ]
    },
    _type: "DOCUMENT",
    _id: {
      $oid: "55c1e7981c49a8cd78818bc3"
    },
```

> ```
>     name: "Soniya",
>     city: "Ernakulam",
>     age: 22,
> ```

```
    _etag: {
      $oid: "55c1e7981c49a8cd78818bc4"
    },
    _lastupdated_on: "2015-08-05T10:38:16Z",
    _created_on: "2015-08-05T10:38:16Z"
  },
  {
    _embedded: {

    },
    _links: {
      self: {
        href: "/jaydb/employees/55c1e7711c49a8cd78818bc1"
      },
      rh: coll: {
        href: "/jaydb"
      },
      curies: [
        {
          href: "http://www.restheart.org/docs/v0.10/#api-doc-{rel}",
          name: "rh"
        }
      ]
    },
    _type: "DOCUMENT",
    _id: {
      $oid: "55c1e7711c49a8cd78818bc1"
    },
```

> ```
>     name: "Reshma",
>     city: "Trivandrum",
>     age: 21,
> ```

```
    _etag: {
      $oid: "55c1e7711c49a8cd78818bc2"
    },
    _lastupdated_on: "2015-08-05T10:37:37Z",
    _created_on: "2015-08-05T10:37:37Z"
  },
  {
    _embedded: {

    },
    _links: {
      self: {
        href: "/jaydb/employees/55c1d3a8b216e0710f8ee0ab"
      },
      rh: coll: {
        href: "/jaydb"
      },
      curies: [
        {
          href: "http://www.restheart.org/docs/v0.10/#api-doc-{rel}",
          name: "rh"
        }
      ]
    },
    _type: "DOCUMENT",
    _id: {
      $oid: "55c1d3a8b216e0710f8ee0ab"
    },
```

> ```
>      name: "Michael",
>      city: "Tokyo",
>      age: 23,
> ```

```
    _created_on: "2015-08-05T09:13:12Z"
  }
]
```

},
      _links: {

```
  },
  _type: "COLLECTION",
  _id: "employees",
  _created_on: "2015-08-05T09:38:36Z",
  _etag: {
    $oid: "55c1d99c1c49a8cd78818bb6"
  },
  _lastupdated_on: "2015-08-05T09:38:36Z",
  _collection-props-cached: false,
  _returned: 5
}
```

Ref: http://restheart.org/docs/walkthrough.html

Answer (score 2):

RESTHeart uses the HAL format, have a look at the [resource representation section](http://restheart.org/docs/resource-representation-format.html) of the restheart documentation for more information.

In summary, your request is a GET to a collection resource: the response includes the collection's own properties at the first level and its documents as embedded resources.

You access the collection's documents via the *_embedded* property that includes the array *rh:doc*; the element of this array are the your documents.

Also note that the documents are paginated: by default RESTHeart returns the first (up to) 1000 documents. You can control the pagination via the *page* and *pagesize* query parameters.

If you also pass the *count* query parameter, you'll get the *_size* and *_total_pages* properties.

The _links parameter includes the *next* and eventually the *previous* links that point to the next and previous page.